# Liferay portlet (with JSF) - pass parameter from one bean to another during redirect

Tags: java, redirect, jsf-2, liferay

I need to pass one parameter (packageId) from one portlet's managed bean (I will call it **beanA**, with ViewScoped) where I do redirect:

```
    LiferayPortletURL url = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(portletRequest,
            PortalUtil.getPortletId(portletRequest), themeDisplay
                    .getLayout().getPlid(), PortletRequest.ACTION_PHASE);   

    url.setParameter("_facesViewIdRender", "/views/esbDeployerView.xhtml");
    url.setParameter("packageId", doc.getId());
    url.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);
    url.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url.toString());
```

to another (**beanB** with ViewScoped) which is invoked by EL (a have a datatable there and call #{esbPackageDetail.services}) in esbDeployerView.xhtml after redirect). beanB is correctly created after redirect but when I try to set a breakpoint in on @PostConstruct method, the parameter value is null.

```
    HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest((PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
    HttpServletRequest oriRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request);
    String esbArchiveId = oriRequest.getParameter("packageId");
```

I have tried also this but the parameter is null again:

```
    LiferayFacesContext liferayFacesContext = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance();
    String hallo = liferayFacesContext.getRequestQueryStringParameter("packageId");
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried this:

```
    boolean parameter = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey("packageId"); 
    boolean parametervalue = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey("cee43b8b-3719-4463-b317-e6fde80707c5");
```

both results are false...

Comment: in your code, whats does "doc" mean?

Comment: How do you redirect to another portlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The problem was in first step. It is necessary to set up PortletRequest to PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE to keep a parameter alive during redirect. Then I was able to read it like:

```
    HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest((PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
    String arumArchiveId = ParamUtil.getString(request, "packageId");
```

@Parkash Kumar Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This might work in your case:

Code sample from where you want to redirect:

```
String redirectURL = "public / private group" + "page_name" + "?packageId=" + doc.getId();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(redirectURL);
```

Code sample to get parameter:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) (externalContext.getRequestMap().get("com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServletRequest"));
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.portlet.request");

String packageId = null;
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = null;
if(portletRequest != null){
    httpRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest));
    packageId = httpRequest.getParameter("packageId");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I dont know what is MemberCenterUtils.HTTP_SERVLET_REQUEST_WEB_KEY...?

Comment: Ohhh sorry, I have updated my answer. Actually, I have saved this web key in my Util property. :p

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working :(. Maybe there is a problem at redirect point? I really dont know..

Comment: Well, instead of redirecting using portlet URL, you may require redirecting to the page where your portlet might have been dropped and then with the help of above given code you can get request parameter.

Comment: In my case, I needed to redirect from one page to another carrying parameters.